Clickhouse FULL OUTER JOIN with coalesce not working
I have 2 CTE's with the 2 columns each. There are NO null values in either CTE.
When I use FULL OUTER JOIN with coalesce im still getting NULL values which is baffling to me.
...
SELECT
  coalesce(c.email, o.email) email,
  o.campaign_opens,
  c.campaign_clicks
FROM campaign_opens o
FULL OUTER JOIN campaign_clicks c ON c.email = o.email

Even when I do this:
  coalesce(c.email, o.email, 'x') email,

There are STILL null values returned. So something about this is definitely not what I'm used to with SQL
What dumb thing am I missing?

Can you create a reproducible example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

I found the problem. clickhouse is defaulting to "" instead of NULL ... I didnt see this anywhere in the docs but i found it in a random clickhouse blogpost. I wrapped each field in NULLIF(x, '') and it worked

This behaviour depends on core settings. There is parameter join_use_nulls.
More details in the documentation
